# AzureAD Powershell Script to Bulk Change Manager Field

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, bulk

1. My goal would be to have a Powershell script that can import a CSV to bulk change a users manager field in AzureAD. The CSV would have 2 columns, one with the user and the other with their manager.
2. I've found scripts to export all users from AzureAD into a CSV, but this doesn't contain a column header for the manager field. I found an AzureAD script than can change the manager field using objectID but that's cumbersome, so ideally I could use an email address for the manager field.
3. I don't have code to show really, these were pretty basic scripts I found but I'm at best a non Powershell user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that you have below file :

[image]

In the left you have the username of the user  and on the right you have the username of the new manager.

You could use the below snippet

```
#connecting to the Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD 

#importing the CSV source which has the changes 
$data = Import-Csv D:\Temp\Book1.csv

#Iterating through each row in the CSV
foreach ($row in $data)
{
#INFO in the Console
Write-Host "Updating the user :"  $row.'User Username'    " manager to "  $row.'Manager Username'  -ForegroundColor Yellow 

#Updating the Manager 
Set-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $row.'User Username').Objectid -RefObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $row.'Manager Username').Objectid

#Completion info in the console for the specified row
Write-Host "Updated." -ForegroundColor Green

}
```

**Explanation :**

**Step 1 :**
Connecting to the Azure AD

**Step 2:**
Importing the CSV data that needs to be bulk updated

**Step 3 :**
Iterating through each row, updating the manager field using the commandlet [Set-AzureADUserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadusermanager?view=azureadps-2.0)

**Sample output :**

[image]

Comment: This looks like exactly what I needed! The missing pieces were how to import the data and swap from email to ObjectIDs. I will give this try a at some point today with a small group of users and see if it works.

Comment: It worked! I had to change the line 'User UPN' to 'User Username' to match the title of the columns, but it worked for at least the first user I tested it on.

Comment: Glad ! I could help :)  I initially had the UPN in the file and code... later changed to have a   friendly name... missed updating in one of the line..  i will have it updated :)

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped  :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: This script used to work for me but it throws an error "Get-AzureADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:7 char:61
+ ... ger -ObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $row.'User Username') -RefOb ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUser"

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzureADUserManager and Set-AzureADUserManager only accept ObjectID as input, similar to quite a few other AzureAD cmdlets.

You will need to have a multi step approach to achieve the outcome, below are the steps I would take

1. Get all Azure AD users, e.g. `$AllAzureADUser = Get-AzureADUser -All`
2. Use calculated property to populate manager field based on `ObjectID` of users you iterate through (essentially this is Foreach loop)

`$AllAzureADUserWithManager = $AllAzureADUser | select *, @{ Name = "ManagerObjectId"; Expression = { Get-AzureADUserManager $_.ObjectId }}`

3. Now you have all data required in $AllAzureADUserWithManager to make decisions and update the object. If you want to use UPN to update you can just look up the `ObjectId` based on UPN.

So say you iterating through an object import from CSV which has `targetUserUPN` and `targetManagerUPN` as columns:

```
$TargetUserObjectId = $AllAzureADUserWithManager | Where {$_.UPN -eq $row.targetUserUPN} | select -ExpandProperty ObjectId
$TargetManagerObjectId = $AllAzureADUserWithManager | Where {$_.UPN -eq $row.targetManagerUPN} | select -ExpandProperty ObjectId
Set-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $TargetUserObjectId -RefObjectId $TargetManagerObjectId
```

If you need to run this on daily basis consider using a delta and export to csv previous runs and Filter down to only what is required if you have large number of users.